# Can there be any issues in using Lumix G 25mm f/1.7 ASPH with Oly OMD10 mark 2?

Tags: lens, olympus, panasonic-lumix, panasonic

I plan to get Lumix G 25mm f/1.7 ASPH for Olympus OMD10 mark 2. 
Should I expect any reduction in performance since I am not using Lumix lens on Lumix camera? I googled but did not find any concrete answer regarding this pair. Some people say stabilization might not work well, but this lens is not stabilized. Some others say about possible purple flare, but only few resources mention this and others say it is not an issue. So I understand it is a very lens dependent question. So I am interested about this pairing specifically!
Thanks.